# How to make HTTP request in Dart with params and header (Uri)

Tags: python-3.x, http, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I wanted to get a request from a API from the website https://rapidapi.com/. Please help me to translate the Python to Dart.

I am able to get the total data using the link  `https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/totals` in place of uri, but unable to get country data by passing the name of the country.

**This is a Python Code and i want this in Dart(Flutter)**

```
import requests

url = "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/country"

querystring = {"format":"undefined","name":"italy"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "84768ddbd5mshe582f65a69666d5p1fea75jsn3a2b9202cc14"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

**This is what i did in Dart. I get the Error**

`{"type":"https:\/\/tools.ietf.org\/html\/rfc2616#section-10","title":"An error occurred","detail":"Parameter name is missing"}`

The Status Code is 400.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NetworkingBrain {
  NetworkingBrain({@required this.params});

  final params;

  Future<void> getData() async {
    try {
      var value = {'country1': params};
      var uri = Uri.parse('https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/country')
          .replace(queryParameters: value)
          .toString();

      http.Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "84768ddbd5mshe582f65a69666d5p1fea75jsn3a2b9202cc14"
      });
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a wrong parameter.

Pass `name` as a `key`

As below:

```
   var value = {'name': params};
```

instead of

```
  var value = {'country1': params};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode json file after getting response. try using following code.

```
Map data;
List userData;
http.Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "84768ddbd5mshe582f65a69666d5p1fea75jsn3a2b9202cc14"
  });
data = json.decode(response.body);
setState(() {
  userData = data['tag of json file'];

});

}
```

Comment: I did this as you told me. 


I am getting this new error

`{type: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10, title: An error occurred, detail: Parameter name is missing}`